# How to set default value in custom option in magento2

Tags: magento2, custom-options, adminform, default-values

I want to set default option to the custom options value in the product level.

How to do that in Magento 2 ?
[image]

Please help me to resolve on this.

Comment: Please explain your question with more details.

Comment: It seems that you are asking to place some default text in your input field.

Comment: in my question I have 2 options m I want to set one option to be the default selected on the frontend.

Comment: How to implement this ? i want to add default value ?

Comment: Here is a solution from Github that worked for me on Magento 2.4.2
https://github.com/dmitrykazak/magento2-custom-option-default-value

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do this via admin. I just did a work around where I made sure all my "default options" are the first option within admin then added the below to js for my store.

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
  $('.product-add-form .field select').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(obj).find('option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
  });
});
</script>
```

This works for custom options as they are all rendered on page load. The code just loops through all custom options and sets the 2nd option as the first was "please select".

I had a bit more difficulty however with configurable products as the options were all loaded after page load but to do that too you can see my question here: [Magento 2: How to set default option in configurable options?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189088/magento-2-how-to-set-default-option-in-configurable-options/189096#189096)

Comment: Check this out: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232072/how-to-make-auto-select-first-child-product-of-configurable-product-in-magento2

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to achieve is something like this?

[image]

I implemented that for the dropdown fields, should be the same with radiobuttons.

1. Add a column for the default option (is_default or whatever) into the table `catalog_product_option_type_value`.
2. Add a plugin which intercepts the modifyMeta method of `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions`.

**Example:**

> vendor/module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions">
    <plugin name="CustomOptionsUiPlugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomOptionsUiPlugin" sortOrder="1"/>
  </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomOptionsUiPlugin.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CustomOptionsUiPlugin
{

...

    public function afterModifyMeta(\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions $subject,$meta)
    {

        $result = $meta;

        $result['custom_options']['children']['options']['children']['record']['children']["container_option"]['children']['values']['children']['record']['children']['is_default'] = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Default'),
                        'componentType' => 'field',
                        'formElement' => 'checkbox',
                        'dataScope' => 'is_default',
                        'dataType' => 'number',
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-small',
                        'sortOrder' => 55,
                        'value' => '0',
                        'valueMap' => [
                            'true' => '1',
                            'false' => '0'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return $result;

    }

}
```

3. And lastly you need to overwrite the file `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select.php` with something like this

   ```
   $defaultAttribute = array();

   if($_value->getData('is_default') == true){
       $defaultAttribute = ['selected' => 'selected','default' => 'default'];
   }

   $select->addOption(
       $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
       $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
       ['price' => $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false),$defaultAttribute]
   );
   ```

   Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks For your solution.
I have tried with your code and I'm able to display "Default" option but custom values are not displaying. Please help me to fix the Issue.

Comment: @TrytoFly adding `$defaultAttribute` as extra attributes for the option will conflict with preconfigured values (buy_request, ...). For example, when editing a cart item, the value selected by the customer **and** the "is_default" value will both be marked as `selected="selected"` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

@TrytoFly This is what worked for me.

```
<?php
namespace Sigma\DefaultCustomOptions\Plugin;

class CustomOptionsUiPlugin
{
       public function afterModifyMeta(
    \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions $subject,
    $result
) {

    $subject;
    $result['custom_options']['children']['options']['children']['record']['children']["container_option"]
    ['children']['values']['children']['record']['children'] =array_replace_recursive(
        $result['custom_options']['children']['options']['children']['record']['children']
        ["container_option"]['children']['values']['children']['record']['children'],
        [
            'is_default' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Default'),
                            'componentType' => 'field',
                            'formElement' => 'checkbox',
                            'dataScope' => 'is_default',
                            'dataType' => 'number',
                            'sortOrder' => 70,
                            'value' => '0',
                            'valueMap' => [
                                'true' => '1',
                                'false' => '0'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    );
    return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please write full code here? By this I'm able to display checkbox with custom option in admin but when I'm going to save product default selected option is not saving. And how to display default selected on front-side?

Answer (score 0):

**You can override  Select.php file like folowing code function :**

```
class AroundOptionValuesHtml extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select
{

    public function getValuesHtml()
    {
        $_option = $this->getOption();
        $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
        $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();

        $this->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1);
        // Remove inline prototype onclick and onchange events

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE
        ) {
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $extraParams = '';
            $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select::class
            )->setData(
                [
                    'id' => 'select_' . $_option->getId(),
                    'class' => $require . ' product-custom-option admin__control-select'
                ]
            );
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getId() . ']')->addOption('', __('-- Please Select --'));
            } else {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getId() . '][]');
                $select->setClass('multiselect admin__control-multiselect' . $require . ' product-custom-option');
            }
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ],
                    false
                );

                // custom code   
                $defaultAttribute = array();
                if($_value->getData('is_default') == true){
                    $defaultAttribute = ['selected' => 'selected'];
                }

                // custom code

                $select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
                    ['price' => $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false),$defaultAttribute]
                );
            }

            // custom code added 

            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
                $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
            }
            if (!$this->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
                $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
            }
            $extraParams .= ' data-selector="' . $select->getName() . '"';
            $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

            if ($configValue) {
                $select->setValue($configValue);
            }

            return $select->getHtml();

        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cleanest way I found to **set a default value for customizable options** :

*(Based on @TrytoFly answer)*

*Note* : I will assume you work on an already created module which I'll call `Vendor_Module`.

#### 1. Add `is_default` column to `catalog_product_option_type_value` table

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0) {
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('catalog_product_option_type_value'),
                'is_default',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    'length' => 1,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => '0',
                    'comment' => 'Defines if Is Default'
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

*Note* : Don't forget to change the version compared according to your module

#### 2. Define and create a plugin to add the checkbox element in the back office

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_custom_options_ui_plugin"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomOptionsUiPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/CustomOptionsUiPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Checkbox;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;

/**
 * Data provider for "Customizable Options" panel
 */
class CustomOptionsUiPlugin
{
    /**
     * Field values
     */
    const FIELD_IS_DEFAULT = 'is_default';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions $subject
     * @param bool $meta
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterModifyMeta(CustomOptions $subject, $meta) {

        $result = $meta;

        $result[CustomOptions::GROUP_CUSTOM_OPTIONS_NAME]['children']
        [CustomOptions::GRID_OPTIONS_NAME]['children']['record']['children']
        [CustomOptions::CONTAINER_OPTION]['children']
        [CustomOptions::GRID_TYPE_SELECT_NAME]['children']['record']['children']
        [static::FIELD_IS_DEFAULT] = $this->getIsDefaultFieldConfig(70);

        return $result;

    }

    /**
     * Get config for checkbox field used for default values
     *
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getIsDefaultFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' =>[
                        'label' => __('Default'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Checkbox::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_IS_DEFAULT,
                        'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-small',
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'value' => '0',
                        'valueMap' => [
                            'true' => '1',
                            'false' => '0'
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

*Note* : Here we use `Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Checkbox` instead of `Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Radio` component as it seems Magento never defines it in its Form Elements.

*See `vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\ui_component\etc\definition.xml` line 112+*

#### 3. Overwrite `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select` to check the element which has been chosen as "Default element".

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select"
                type="Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Catalog\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Rewrite/Catalog/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Catalog\Product\View\Options\Type;

/**
 * Product options text type block
 */
class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select
{
    /**
     * Return html for control element
     *
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function getValuesHtml()
    {
        $_option = $this->getOption();
        $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
        $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();

        $this->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1);
        // Remove inline prototype onclick and onchange events

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE
        ) {
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $extraParams = '';
            $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select::class
            )->setData(
                [
                    'id' => 'select_' . $_option->getId(),
                    'class' => $require . ' product-custom-option admin__control-select'
                ]
            );
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getId() . ']')->addOption('', __('-- Please Select --'));
            } else {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getId() . '][]');
                $select->setClass('multiselect admin__control-multiselect' . $require . ' product-custom-option');
            }
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ],
                    false
                );

                if($_value->getData('is_default') == true && !$configValue){
                    $configValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
                }
                $select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
                    ['price' => $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false)]
                );
            }
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
                $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
            }
            if (!$this->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
                $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
            }
            $extraParams .= ' data-selector="' . $select->getName() . '"';
            $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

            if ($configValue) {
                $select->setValue($configValue);
            }

            return $select->getHtml();
        }

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
        ) {
            $selectHtml = '<div class="options-list nested" id="options-' . $_option->getId() . '-list">';
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $arraySign = '';
            switch ($_option->getType()) {
                case \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                    $type = 'radio';
                    $class = 'radio admin__control-radio';
                    if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
                        $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option">' .
                            '<input type="radio" id="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '" class="' .
                            $class .
                            ' product-custom-option" name="options[' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            ']"' .
                            ' data-selector="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"' .
                            ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                            ' value="" checked="checked" /><label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '"><span>' .
                            __('None') . '</span></label></div>';
                    }
                    break;
                case \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                    $type = 'checkbox';
                    $class = 'checkbox admin__control-checkbox';
                    $arraySign = '[]';
                    break;
            }
            $count = 1;
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $count++;

                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ]
                );

                $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $checked = is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue) ? 'checked' : '';
                } else {
                    $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
                }

                $dataSelector = 'options[' . $_option->getId() . ']';
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $dataSelector .= '[' . $htmlValue . ']';
                }

                $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option' .
                    $require .
                    '">' .
                    '<input type="' .
                    $type .
                    '" class="' .
                    $class .
                    ' ' .
                    $require .
                    ' product-custom-option"' .
                    ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                    ' name="options[' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    ']' .
                    $arraySign .
                    '" id="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '" value="' .
                    $htmlValue .
                    '" ' .
                    $checked .
                    ' data-selector="' . $dataSelector . '"' .
                    ' price="' .
                    $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) .
                    '" />' .
                    '<label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '"><span>' .
                    $_value->getTitle() .
                    '</span> ' .
                    $priceStr .
                    '</label>';
                $selectHtml .= '</div>';
            }
            $selectHtml .= '</div>';

            return $selectHtml;
        }
    }
}
```

#### **4. Upgrade your module version and update the database**

Upgrade your `setup_version` in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml`

Update your `version` in  `app/code/Vendor/Module/composer.json`

Run following commands :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```