# How to add radio button to set default value for Customizable Options in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, product, custom-options, default-values

How to add radio button to set default value for product custom options (Customizable Options) in Magento2 Admin grid

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution from Github that worked for me on Magento 2.4.2
https://github.com/dmitrykazak/magento2-custom-option-default-value

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cleanest way I found to **set a default value for customizable options** :

*(Based on answers on [this similar question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165801/how-to-set-default-value-in-custom-option-in-magento2/))*

*Note* : I will assume you work on an already created module which I'll call `Vendor_Module`.

#### 1. Add `is_default` column to `catalog_product_option_type_value` table

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.1') < 0) {
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('catalog_product_option_type_value'),
                'is_default',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    'length' => 1,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => '0',
                    'comment' => 'Defines if Is Default'
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

*Note* : Don't forget to change the version compared according to your module

#### 2. Define and create a plugin to add the checkbox element in the back office

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_custom_options_ui_plugin"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomOptionsUiPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/CustomOptionsUiPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Checkbox;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;

/**
 * Data provider for "Customizable Options" panel
 */
class CustomOptionsUiPlugin
{
    /**
     * Field values
     */
    const FIELD_IS_DEFAULT = 'is_default';

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions $subject
     * @param bool $meta
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterModifyMeta(CustomOptions $subject, $meta) {

        $result = $meta;

        $result[CustomOptions::GROUP_CUSTOM_OPTIONS_NAME]['children']
        [CustomOptions::GRID_OPTIONS_NAME]['children']['record']['children']
        [CustomOptions::CONTAINER_OPTION]['children']
        [CustomOptions::GRID_TYPE_SELECT_NAME]['children']['record']['children']
        [static::FIELD_IS_DEFAULT] = $this->getIsDefaultFieldConfig(70);

        return $result;

    }

    /**
     * Get config for checkbox field used for default values
     *
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getIsDefaultFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' =>[
                        'label' => __('Default'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Checkbox::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_IS_DEFAULT,
                        'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-small',
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'value' => '0',
                        'valueMap' => [
                            'true' => '1',
                            'false' => '0'
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

*Note* : Here we use `Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Checkbox` instead of `Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Radio` component as it seems Magento never defines it in its Form Elements.

*See `vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\ui_component\etc\definition.xml` line 112+*

#### 3. Overwrite `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select` to check the element which has been chosen as "Default element".

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select"
                type="Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Catalog\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Rewrite/Catalog/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Rewrite\Catalog\Product\View\Options\Type;

/**
 * Product options text type block
 */
class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select
{
    /**
     * Return html for control element
     *
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function getValuesHtml()
    {
        $_option = $this->getOption();
        $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
        $store = $this->getProduct()->getStore();

        $this->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1);
        // Remove inline prototype onclick and onchange events

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE
        ) {
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $extraParams = '';
            $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select::class
            )->setData(
                [
                    'id' => 'select_' . $_option->getId(),
                    'class' => $require . ' product-custom-option admin__control-select'
                ]
            );
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getId() . ']')->addOption('', __('-- Please Select --'));
            } else {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getId() . '][]');
                $select->setClass('multiselect admin__control-multiselect' . $require . ' product-custom-option');
            }
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ],
                    false
                );

                if($_value->getData('is_default') == true && !$configValue) {
                    $configValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
                }
                $select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
                    ['price' => $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false)]
                );
            }
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
                $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
            }
            if (!$this->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
                $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
            }
            $extraParams .= ' data-selector="' . $select->getName() . '"';
            $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

            if ($configValue) {
                $select->setValue($configValue);
            }

            return $select->getHtml();
        }

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
        ) {
            $selectHtml = '<div class="options-list nested" id="options-' . $_option->getId() . '-list">';
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $arraySign = '';
            switch ($_option->getType()) {
                case \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                    $type = 'radio';
                    $class = 'radio admin__control-radio';
                    if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
                        $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option">' .
                            '<input type="radio" id="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '" class="' .
                            $class .
                            ' product-custom-option" name="options[' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            ']"' .
                            ' data-selector="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"' .
                            ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                            ' value="" checked="checked" /><label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '"><span>' .
                            __('None') . '</span></label></div>';
                    }
                    break;
                case \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                    $type = 'checkbox';
                    $class = 'checkbox admin__control-checkbox';
                    $arraySign = '[]';
                    break;
            }
            $count = 1;
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $count++;

                $priceStr = $this->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ]
                );

                $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $checked = is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue) ? 'checked' : '';
                } else {
                    $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
                }

                $dataSelector = 'options[' . $_option->getId() . ']';
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $dataSelector .= '[' . $htmlValue . ']';
                }

                $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option' .
                    $require .
                    '">' .
                    '<input type="' .
                    $type .
                    '" class="' .
                    $class .
                    ' ' .
                    $require .
                    ' product-custom-option"' .
                    ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                    ' name="options[' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    ']' .
                    $arraySign .
                    '" id="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '" value="' .
                    $htmlValue .
                    '" ' .
                    $checked .
                    ' data-selector="' . $dataSelector . '"' .
                    ' price="' .
                    $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) .
                    '" />' .
                    '<label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '"><span>' .
                    $_value->getTitle() .
                    '</span> ' .
                    $priceStr .
                    '</label>';
                $selectHtml .= '</div>';
            }
            $selectHtml .= '</div>';

            return $selectHtml;
        }
    }
}
```

#### **4. Upgrade your module version and update the database**

Upgrade your `setup_version` in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml`

Update your `version` in  `app/code/Vendor/Module/composer.json`

Run following commands :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```