# How to make auto select first child product of configurable product in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configurable-product, magento2.2, select

I am trying to make auto select first child product from the configurable product in product detail page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**For Dropdown:**

Override this file to your theme:

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js

your theme file location will be:

> app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js

Replace the **_fillSelect** method under **configurable.js**

```
_fillSelect: function (element) {
    var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, ''),
        options = this._getAttributeOptions(attributeId),
        prevConfig,
        index = 1,
        allowedProducts,
        i,
        j;

    this._clearSelect(element);
    element.options[0] = new Option('', '');
    element.options[0].innerHTML = this.options.spConfig.chooseText;
    prevConfig = false;

    if (element.prevSetting) {
        prevConfig = element.prevSetting.options[element.prevSetting.selectedIndex];
    }

    if (options) {
        for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            allowedProducts = [];
            if (prevConfig) {
                for (j = 0; j < options[i].products.length; j++) {
                    // prevConfig.config can be undefined
                    if (prevConfig.config &&
                        prevConfig.config.allowedProducts &&
                        prevConfig.config.allowedProducts.indexOf(options[i].products[j]) > -1) {
                        allowedProducts.push(options[i].products[j]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                allowedProducts = options[i].products.slice(0);
            }

            if (allowedProducts.length > 0) {
                options[i].allowedProducts = allowedProducts;
                element.options[index] = new Option(this._getOptionLabel(options[i]), options[i].id);
                if (typeof options[i].price !== 'undefined') {
                    element.options[index].setAttribute('price', options[i].prices);
                }

                element.options[index].config = options[i];




                index++;
            }
            // Code added to select option
            if (i == 0) {
                this.options.values[attributeId] = options[i].id;
            }   
        }
        //Code added to check if configurations are set in url and resets them if needed 
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1) {this._parseQueryParams(window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf('#') + 1));}
    }

},
```

**For Swatch:**
Override the below file to your theme

> /module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/SwatchRenderer.js

And update the method **_RenderControls**

```
_RenderControls: function () {
    var $widget = this,
        container = this.element,
        classes = this.options.classes,
        chooseText = this.options.jsonConfig.chooseText,
        selectedArray = []; // Variable declation for autoselect element array

    $widget.optionsMap = {};

    $.each(this.options.jsonConfig.attributes, function () {
        var item = this,
            controlLabelId = 'option-label-' + item.code + '-' + item.id,
            options = $widget._RenderSwatchOptions(item, controlLabelId),
            select = $widget._RenderSwatchSelect(item, chooseText),
            input = $widget._RenderFormInput(item),
            listLabel = '',
            label = '';

        // Show only swatch controls
        if ($widget.options.onlySwatches && !$widget.options.jsonSwatchConfig.hasOwnProperty(item.id)) {
            return;
        }

        if ($widget.options.enableControlLabel) {
            label +=
                '<span id="' + controlLabelId + '" class="' + classes.attributeLabelClass + '">' +
                    item.label +
                '</span>' +
                '<span class="' + classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass + '"></span>';
        }

        if ($widget.inProductList) {
            $widget.productForm.append(input);
            input = '';
            listLabel = 'aria-label="' + item.label + '"';
        } else {
            listLabel = 'aria-labelledby="' + controlLabelId + '"';
        }

        // Create new control
        container.append(
            '<div class="' + classes.attributeClass + ' ' + item.code + '" ' +
                 'attribute-code="' + item.code + '" ' +
                 'attribute-id="' + item.id + '">' +
                label +
                '<div aria-activedescendant="" ' +
                     'tabindex="0" ' +
                     'aria-invalid="false" ' +
                     'aria-required="true" ' +
                     'role="listbox" ' + listLabel +
                     'class="' + classes.attributeOptionsWrapper + ' clearfix">' +
                    options + select +
                '</div>' + input +
            '</div>'
        );

        $widget.optionsMap[item.id] = {};

        // Aggregate options array to hash (key => value)
        $.each(item.options, function () {
            if (this.products.length > 0) {
                $widget.optionsMap[item.id][this.id] = {
                    price: parseInt(
                        $widget.options.jsonConfig.optionPrices[this.products[0]].finalPrice.amount,
                        10
                    ),
                    products: this.products
                };
            }
        });
        //Create array for Autoselect swatch
        selectedArray.push($widget.element.find('[attribute-id=' + item.id + '] .swatch-option')[0]);
    });


    // Connect Tooltip
    container
        .find('[option-type="1"], [option-type="2"], [option-type="0"], [option-type="3"]')
        .SwatchRendererTooltip();

    // Hide all elements below more button
    $('.' + classes.moreButton).nextAll().hide();

    // Handle events like click or change
    $widget._EventListener();

    // Rewind options
    $widget._Rewind(container);

    //Emulate click on all swatches from Request
    $widget._EmulateSelected($.parseQuery());
    $widget._EmulateSelected($widget._getSelectedAttributes());

    //Trigger click for Autoselect first option swatch
    $.each(selectedArray, function () {
        if(this != undefined) this.click();
    });

},
```

Comment: Hello, i am using module swatch , the above code is for drop downs i guess, can we make it work for swatches also?

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: checked but i am getting $.parseParams is not a function error

Comment: Happy to help!. Upvote please when reach to 15.

Comment: Sure!!! . i will upvote

Comment: hi @SukumarGorai can you help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246502/magento-2-configurable-product-variation-dropdown-attribute-s-want-to-select-aut

Comment: Not working for swatch i need help go to my question "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257577/magento2-how-to-remove-choose-an-option-in-configurable-products-drop-down/258144?noredirect=1#comment363515_258144"

Comment: @SukumarGorai Please look it and reply my question "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257577/magento2-how-to-remove-choose-an-option-in-configurable-products-drop-down/258144?noredirect=1#comment363515_258144"

Comment: I have tried the same and its working fine in magento 2.3 , but getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateData' of undefined

Comment: i am getting same error @vellaidurai. have you got solution?

Comment: After upgrading to 2.3.1 this method stopped working for some dropdowns. I'm not entirely sure why but the fix was easy, just change 

`if (i == 0)`

to

`if (i === 0)`

Comment: Thanks this code is working perfectly for magento 2.3 also

Comment: Code is working perfectly

Comment: I try on configurable.js and auto select working fine. But the image is not changed.

Comment: Thanks sukumar instead of theme how to override the same function from custom module?

Comment: You can override it through requireconfig.js

Comment: can u guide me the what are the steps need to be follow.

Comment: Write a different question so that users can help and answer to your question.

Comment: @SukumarGorai please suggest https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/299393/magento-2-create-custom-product-link-type

Comment: @SukumarGorai, in list page all config products are 0 price, this fix will resolve that error?

Comment: it is not working in some products. All options are as dropdown. I am using 2.3.2

Comment: @SukumarGorai, Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution for swatches, you can add a JS file in your (child)theme for layout `catalog_product_view.xml`

JS file content:

```
require(["jquery"],function($){
  $(document).on('swatch.initialized', function() { 
    $(".swatch-attribute.color .swatch-option").first().not(".selected").click();
  });
});
```