# How to select by default first swatches from dependent options color & size in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, tierprice, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

I have tier prices for the products but it is showing after selecting swatches.

I have two attributes  **"Color & Size"**
 for configurable products.

**Color attributes have swatch image** and **Size attribute as dropdown**.

I want to show selected by default first option for both attributes of the products.

I am using magento 2.2

I have tried another solution bt not getting success. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232072/how-to-make-auto-select-first-child-product-of-configurable-product-in-magento2/232076#232076 Check this solution.

Comment: I have tried but it is not working. Please check screenshot: http://nimb.ws/8OlwSY

I want select first color and first size.

Comment: Are you using any extension or its a default? If default then run static-content deploy, flush the cache and try again.

Comment: No extension, it's default.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, It is working only with dropdown. But I have color as Swatches and Size as dropdown.