# Magento 2.3.1 - Configurable products auto select first option

Tags: magento2, product, php, configurable-product, magento2.3

how I can auto select the first associated product in configurable product on Magento 2.3.1.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems the duplicate question,

Please refer here.

[How to make auto select first child product of configurable product in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232072/how-to-make-auto-select-first-child-product-of-configurable-product-in-magento2)

Comment: but how I can change the name and other attributes like description and so on with the associated product?