# magento 2 How to show Simple product images instead of configurable product images?

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, magento2.3, media-images

In Default Magento, For configurable product in product detail page product media displays images of configurable product by default,but i want to show simple products images in product media instead of configurable images.

How can i do that?

Comment: You can change image display setting from backend. Store->Configurations->Sales->Checkout https://prnt.sc/olwyjj

Comment: @KKR i think this is for minicart and cart page not for product detail page

Comment: To display a simple product image, options of that products should remain selected. For that you can refer to below link:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232072/how-to-make-auto-select-first-child-product-of-configurable-product-in-magento2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show simple products images rather than vistual swatch go to store -> product here your all products attribute will be show then edit that attribute whose visual swatch show in store front in configurable product let suppose it is color attribute in its attribute edit form you will see a Dropdown with name (Use Product Image for Swatch if Possible) select yes option and save the attribute then flush page cache and see on front-store simple products images will show rather then visual swatch